# Google Map API (JS) - Show multiple locations in Google map but One after One

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am using following code for displaying multiple locations on Map using Google MAP JS API.

[Code](https://gist.github.com/parth1020/4481893)

But I want to display the Second marker after reaching at first location, and Third marker after reaching Second Location and so on. Not all marker in Once.
As per the code, I want to show "Coogee Beach" Marker in the map, If I reached at Bondi Beach and so on. One Marker at one time.

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no simple way to know if you reached a position or not,what you could do here is to use distanceMatrixService to get the distances between the origin and your position lets call it distanceA and the distance between the origin and a place lets call it distanceB, and the algorithm would be something like :

```
if(distanceA>distanceB){
     addMarker(locations[i+1]);
     distanceB=distance between the origin and the next location;
     i++;
}
```

here is a link to the distanceMatrixService
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/distance-matrix